# "was getting ready to go out"

Tags: phrase-usage

How do you understand "was getting ready to go out"? Does it mean that something happened and defeated their schedule or they went out as it was planned? In what context can be used that sentence?

It's from my grammar book.

> I was getting ready to go out at 7:45 p.m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the uses for the past continuous/progressive tense is to describe an interrupted action, but that's not what's going on here.

Another, perhaps more straightforward, use of the past continuous is to describe an ongoing activity that took place at a certain time.

> When you mention an exact time in the past, use the past continuous tense if the action started before that time and continued afterward. If the action begins at the time mentioned, use the simple past instead.
>
> Past continuous tense examples:
>
> At midnight, everyone at the party was still having fun.
>
> I was working as a cashier in October.
>
> By the age of nine, I was training to be a ninja.

[Past Continuous Tense: How and When to Use It, With Examples](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-continuous-tense/)

The simplest context where this sentence would make sense would be as an answer to the question, "What were you doing at 7:45?"  Other, more likely contexts, would probably demand that the example sentence be altered in some way.

For example, if you wanted to describe being interrupted, "I was getting ready to go out at 7:45, when someone knocked at my door."  Or, you could emphasize that the activity was going on longer than expected like this, "I was *still* getting ready to go out at 7:45."

Comment: Your answer is good for describing the past continuous and I have known some additional details about that tense, but my question is more about the phrase "getting ready" in context with the past continuous. I try to translate that phrase correctly, that's why I need to understand the full meaning of that phrase.

Comment: If I understand right, there are two meanings of that phrase in mentioned context. 1) I was getting ready to go out at 7:45 and I did it on time to get on a bus. 2) I was getting ready to go out at 7:45 but when I washed my hair, the hot water was off by someone and I was late.

Comment: Is that right usage of that phrase?

Answer (score 0):

That sentence is ambiguous.

It could mean:

> (1) At 7:45 pm, I was getting ready to go out. My plan was to go out at a later time.

or it could mean:

> (2) I had plans to go out at 7:45 pm, so I was getting ready before that time.

The actual meaning would be determined from the context.

Comment: You wrote that the sentence is ambiguous but I don't see that with your examples. Please see my examples, whether I understand right that ambiguous.

Comment: 1) I was getting ready to go out at 7:45 and I did it and got on a bus on time. 2) I was getting ready to go out at 7:45 but when I washed my hair, the hot water was off by someone and I was late.

Comment: @Sergei I've reworded my examples for clarity

Comment: The sentence only means that I was preparing to go out. It doesn't say whether I went out or not.